Show VSTO side panel in Outlook 2 seconds after an inspector is created -> Black blink
I need to create a VSTO project that simply shows a side panel 2 seconds after an inspector is created. So I register the New Inspector event and inside it I do:
        /*********************************************************************/
        private void Inspectors_NewInspector(Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Inspector.CurrentItem is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)
                {
                    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
                    if (mailItem != null)
                    {
                            System.Windows.Forms.Timer delayTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
                            delayTimer.Interval = 2000;
                            delayTimer.Enabled = true;
                            delayTimer.Tick += DelayTimerInspector_Tick;
                            NewInspectorData inspectorData = new NewInspectorData();
                            inspectorData.mailItem = mailItem;
                            inspectorData.inspector = Inspector;
                            delayTimer.Tag = inspectorData;
                            delayTimer.Start();
                            return;
             ...

        private void DelayTimerInspector_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            try
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = (System.Windows.Forms.Timer)sender;
                timer.Stop();
                NewInspectorData inspectorData = (NewInspectorData)timer.Tag;
                Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane panel = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new UserControl(), "TEST", inspectorData.inspector);
                panel.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }




The problemn is that nearnly 1 time on 10 (you must open different emails to avoid the inspector from getting cached) I see a black area for few milliseconds in the user control.
I see this should work fine, I don't see the reason why there is such that bad behavior.
Any idea?
Thanks
The black blink should no happen
